# How do I hide specific dropdown li's from navbar in css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar with some elements that should be visible for everybody, some that should be visible for users and some that should be visible for admins. I have assigned them the appropriate classes and items inside the dropdowns can be hidden accordingly, but not the dropdowns themselves.

Ie:

```
<li class="dropdown user">
 <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">This <span class="caret"></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li class="admin"><a href="#">That</a></li>
   <li class="user"><a href="#">Something else</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

If I am not logged in I don't want ANY part of that dropdown element showing. A user will see the "This" dropdown and the "Something else" menu choice but not "That". An admin, however, will see it all.

But even if the menuchoices get hidden, the dropdown does not.

```
.user{ display:none;}
```

for example will hide "Something else" but not "This" regardless if admin is visible or not. visibility:hidden; sort of works, but there is still a placeholder for the link wich ofcourse looks odd.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the selector like `li li.admin` or `li li.user`. Check below example by clicking on `View Admin Menu`

```js
$(function() {
  $('#admin').click(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == 'View Admin Menu')
      $(this).text('View User Menu');
    else
      $(this).text('View Admin Menu');

    $('li li.admin').toggle();
  });
})
```

```css
li li.admin {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="admin" href="#">View Admin Menu</a>
<br>
<br>
<li class="dropdown user">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">This <span class="caret"></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="admin"><a href="#">That</a>
    </li>
    <li class="user"><a href="#">Something else</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: But how can I hide directly from the navbar? If I wanted to hide "This" and any child elements?

because using li li.user will still ONLY hide child elements.

Answer (score 0):

I will add a more complete view of my navbar so you might get a better understanding of what I'm trying to do.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                </button>
                <div class="brand-logos">
                    <a id="something" class="brand" href="#"><img src="some image" id="something" alt="Some text"></a><br />
                    <a id="something" class="brand nohoverlink" href="index.html">Some text</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <div class="navbar-right">
                    <a href="en/index.html"><img border=0 src="flag picture" id="flag"/>&nbsp;In English</a><BR>
                    <a href="#">A link</a><BR>
                    <img src="a picture" />
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown user">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">User and admin can see <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="user"><a href="#" Title="Something">User and admin can see</a></li>
                            <li class="user"><a href="#" TITLE="Something">User and admin can see</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" title="">Everybody can see <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="user"><a href="#">User and admin can see</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Every body can see</a></li>
                        <li class="admin"><a href="#" TITLE="">Only admin can see</a></li>
                        <li class="admin"><a href="#" TITLE="">Only admin can see</a></li>
                        <li class="admin"><a href="#" TITLE="">Only admin can see</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Everybody can see <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#" title="">Every body can see</a></li>
                            <li class="user"><a href="#" title="">User and admin can see</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="user"><a href="#">User and admin can see</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Every body can see <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#" title="">Every body can see</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Every body can see</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Every body can see</a></li>
                                <li class="admin"><a href="#" TITLE="">Only admin can see</a></li>
                                <li class="user"><a href="#" TITLE="">User and admin can see</a></li>
                                <li class="admin"><a href="#" TITLE="">Only admin can see</a></li>
                                <li class="admin"><a href="#" TITLE="">Only admin can see</a></li>
                                <li class="admin"><a href="#" TITLE="">Only admin can see</a></li>
                                <li class="admin"><a href="#" TITLE="">Only admin can see</a></li>
                                <li class="admin"><a href="#" TITLE="">Only admin can see</a></li>
                                <li class="admin"><a href="#" TITLE="">Only admin can see</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" TITLE="">Every body can see</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown user">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">User and admin can see <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="admin"><a href="#" TITLE="">Only admin can see</a></li>
                                <li class="user"><a href="#" TITLE="">User and admin can see</a></li>
                                <li class="admin"><a href="#" Title="">Only admin can see</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Every body can see <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#" title="">Every body can see</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="">Every body can see</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```